# Count Rows after particular Row in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count number of Rows between two header rows.

For example, I'm trying to count the Rows between the removed and Retained Headers. Some times the retained header and rows after that may not exist. So I'm planning to count the rows after Removed header in table.

Example Table : header Rows are Rows with Text Added, Removed, Retained.

Added

ROW1

Row2 

Removed 

Row3 

Row4

Row5 

Retained

Row6

Row7

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTML instead of just a textual representation of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/pUV3u/

```
   var count = $('#Removed').nextUntil('#Retained').length;
```

Count to the end after #Removed -

```
var countTheRest = $('#Removed').nextAll('tr').length;
```

Comment: +1 Great answer.  I didn't know about [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)